# autocomplete multiple fields

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want the autocomplete using AJAX. but it doesn't display anything when i type on the textbox. It would be great if you find the problem.

```
 <html>
  <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
 $('#item_1').autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'ajax.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
               name_startsWith: request.term,
               type: 'item_table',
               row_num : 1
            },
             success: function( data ) {
                 response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    var code = item.split("|");
                    return {
                        label: code[0],
                        value: code[0],
                        data : item
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    autoFocus: true,            
    minLength: 0,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        var names = ui.item.data.split("|");                        
        $('#code_1').val(names[1]);
        $('#description_1').val(names[2]);
        $('#quantity_1').val(names[3]);
    }               
});
 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <form action=""  method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="item[]" id="item_1" class="ui-autocomplete-input">
    <input type="text" name="code[]" id="code_1" class="ui-autocomplete-input">
    <input type="text" name="description[]" id="description_1" class="ui-autocomplete-input">
    <input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_1" class="ui-autocomplete-input">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

AJAX.PHP
My query when will find the search keyword and will display automatically on multiple textboxes.

```
require_once 'dbconnection.php';
if($_POST['type'] == 'item_table'){
    $row_num = $_POST['row_num'];
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT item, code, description, quantity FROM item_tb where item LIKE '".strtoupper($_POST['name_startsWith'])."%'");    
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $name = $row['item'].'|'.$row['code'].'|'.$row['description'].'|'.$row['quantity'].'|'.$row_num;
        array_push($data, $name);   
    }   
    echo json_encode($data);
}


?>
```

Comment: `<head>` after `</html>`??? :o How would it work then??

Comment: Did you check the console? What did it say?

Comment: And you should also consider escaping your input. This is open to SQL injection attacks

Comment: No. can you help me how to check?

Comment: No problem with that. this is my only problem.

Comment: You are not even loading any autocomplete plugin, how do you expect it to work? Use your browser console to track Javascript errors and solve them one by one until the page is error free, you will plainly see a "TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function" or similar because there is no autocomplete function defined anywhere in your code/linked resources.

Answer (score 1):

I done this before some time on a site, check its header's search bar: `http://jhm.co.nz/`

I customized it for you,
my json looks like:

```
[
    {"id":"1","type":"product","name":"Q10 Soy oner"},
    {"id":"3","type":"product","name":"SoyLotion Toner"}
]
```

and my script is:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#headerSearch" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 1,
        source: 'https://www.jhm.co.nz/ajaxSearch.php',
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            name = ui.item.name;
            $( "#headerSearch" ).val( name );
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {

            $( "#headerSearch" ).val( ui.item.name );
            $( "#headerSearchId" ).val( ui.item.id );
            $( "#headerSearchType" ).val( ui.item.type );
            return false;
        }

}).autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        document.getElementById('headerSearch').className='ui-autocomplete-input';
        return $( "<li>" ).append( "<a>" + item.name + "</a>" ).appendTo( ul );
    };
})
```

#headerSearchId, #headerSearchType are ids of hidden fields, in my case, you just make 3 input text fields and give them ids like #headerSearch, #headerSearchId, #headerSearchType, autocomplete will apply on #headerSearch, also need to modify your json, like my above.

Comment: thanks for the effort. but i dont know how will apply in mine.